# App displaying color slightly differently on different devices

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-color

I have defined following background color in my layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/appTheme"
/>
```

The `@color` is defined in `colors.xml` file.

```
<color name="appTheme">#002B5C</color>
```

Now when i run the applicaton in `samsung s8`, which has `Oreo 8.0` installed, it displays a color little differently.

When i take screenshot of my screen, and gets its color code, i get `#012b5d`

However this displays exact same color in `Samsung s5`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your default app theme. The Android platform provides a collection of styles and themes that you can use(inherit) in your app. But the default theme may have some differences in another android version.

Try to create your own style and use as the app theme.